# How to create empty 2d array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I  create an empty 2D array in Javascript (without knowing how many rows or columns there will be in the new array)?

If it's a simple array `var newArray = new Array();` I can assign as many elements as I want. But what about a 2D array? Can I create one without specifying the numbers of rows and columns? and how do I access the elements afterwards (`myArray[0][1]` or `myArray[0,1]`)?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495187/best-way-to-generate-empty-2d-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521796/is-it-possible-to-create-an-empty-multidimensional-array-in-javascript-jquery and many more

Comment: I assumed that `var row_major = Array(height).map(function () { return Array(width); });` would do the trick, but finally needed a 2D array today and found that it doesn't.  Damn.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes you can create an empty array and then push data into it. There is no need to define the length first in JavaScript.
 Check out **[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/zrnr9/317/)**

Define:

```
const arr = [[],[]];
```

Push data:

```
arr[0][2] = 'Hi Mr.A';
arr[1][3] = 'Hi Mr.B';
```

Read data:

```
alert(arr[0][2]);
alert(arr[1][3]);
```

Update: 

Here is also a video recommended by Brady Dowling: 
Create a 2D array: ([https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMeDkp1J2OM][2])

Comment: and how do we define it then `new Array ()()`?

Comment: @meks Like this: `new Array([])`, Check Out the demo. Did the answer solve your problem ?

Comment: For dynamic population of array please see Guffa's answer down here.

Comment: Not exactly ... NOT.  This only works because the first index increments each assignment.  If you try arr[7][7] = 'Hi Mr.C' then you get a "cannot set property" error

Answer (score 105):

You can create a 6 x 6 empty array like this:

```
var myGrid = [...Array(6)].map(e => Array(6));
```

- `Array(6)` generates an array with length = 6 and full of `undefined` values.
- We map that array to another array full of `undefined` values.
- In the end, we get a 6x6 grid full of `undefined` positions.

If you need to initialize the grid with a default value:

```
var value = 'foo'; // by default
var myGrid = [...Array(6)].map(e => Array(6).fill(value));
```

Now you have a 6 x 6 grid full of `'foo'`.

Comment: Underrated trick right here ^^^ works great for arbitrary 2D arrays.

Here it is in reusable form:

`const create2dArray = (rows, columns) => [...Array(rows).keys()].map(i => Array(columns)) `

Comment: Further explanations would be nice ;)

Comment: What is the point of using `[...Array(6)]` instead of just `Array(6)`?

Comment: @nog642 you cannot iterate the array resulting of `Array(6)` because it has no elements, but the array resulting of `[...Array(6)]` contains 6 undefined elements and you can iterate/map them

Comment: You don't need the `e` in the map function. You can use empty parenthesis: `.map( () => Array(6).fill(value)`

Answer (score 14):

There are no two dimensional arrays in Javascript.

To accomplish the effect of a two dimensional array, you use an array of arrays, also known as a jagged array (because the inner arrays can have different length).

An empty jagged array is created just like any other empty array:

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

You can also use an empty array literal:

```
var myArray = [];
```

To put any items in the jagged array, you first have to put inner arrays in it, for example like this:

```
myArray.push([]);
myArray[0][0] = 'hello';
```

You can also create an array that contains a number of empty arrays from start:

```
var myArray = [[],[],[]];
```

That gives you a jagged array without any items, but which is prepared with three inner arrays.

As it's an array of arrays, you access the items using `myArray[0][1]`.

Comment: A clean concept for 2D array.

Answer (score 14):

Say you wanted to make a 2d array (i.e. matrix) that's 100x100, you can do it in one line, like this:

```
var 2darray = new Array(100).fill(null).map(()=>new Array(100).fill(null));
```

This will create a 100x100 matrix of NULL's.
Replace the 100x100 with whatever dimensions you want, and the null's with whatever is your prefered default value, or blank for undefined.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple for loop to create an array of the approximate size and then push more rows if need be.

```
const arr = [];
const n = 7;
const m = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push(new Array(m).fill(0));
}
```

```js
const arr = [];
const n = 7;
const m = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push(new Array(m).fill(0));
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

The functions I use

```
function get_empty_2d_array(numRows, numColumnns) {
  return [...Array(numRows)].map(e => Array(numColumnns));
}

function get_2d_array_filled(numRows, numColumnns, fillValue) {
  return [...Array(numRows)].map(e => Array(numColumnns).fill(fillValue));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) The array length property improperly reports the array length if called  after the var myArray = [[],[]]; statement.   Technically, since the empty arrays are defined, they are getting counted by the length property, but in the spirit of the length property it really should return 0, because no non-empty elements have been added to any of the arrays.

A minimum work around is to use two nested for( in ) loops, one for the 1st array and one for the 2nd array, and to count the non-undefined elements.

2) Extending Siamak A.Motlagh example and adding a arr([2][4]) = 'Hi Mr.C'; assignment fails with an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '4' of undefined" error.

See the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howardb1/zq8oL2ds/

Here is a copy of that code:

```
var arr = [[],[]];

alert( arr.length );  // wrong!

var c = 0;
for( var i in arr )
  for( var j in arr[ i ] )
    if( arr[ i ][ j ] != undefined )
      ++c;
alert( c );  // correct

arr[0][2] = 'Hi Mr.A';
alert(arr[0][2]);

arr[1][3] = 'Hi Mr.B';
alert(arr[1][3]);

arr[2][4] = 'Hi Mr.C';  // At this point I'm getting VM558:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '4' of undefined
alert(arr[2][4]);

var c = 0;
for( var i in arr )
  for( var j in arr[ i ] )
    if( arr[ i ][ j ] != undefined )
      ++c;
alert( c );
```

Why does the third assignment fail?  What about the [[],[]] creation statement told it that the first array was valid for 0 and 1, but not 2 or that 2 and 3 were ok for the second array, but not 4?

Most importantly, how would I define an Array in an Array that could hold date objects in the first and second arrays.  I'm using the jQuery-UI DatePicker, which expects an array of dates, as in date objects, which I've extended to use a second date array to contain date objects that contain times so I can keep track of multiple dates, and multiple times per day.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does the third assignment fail? What about the [[],[]] creation statement told it that the first array was valid for 0 and 1, but not 2 or that 2 and 3 were ok for the second array, but not 4?

This is my nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [
    ["cats","dogs","monkeys","horses"],
    ["apples","oranges","pears","bananas"]
];
document.write(myArray[0][2]) //returns "monkeys"
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works as an expression:

```
var twoDarr= new Array(desiredLength);
for (i=0;i<twoDarr.length;i++) {twoDarr[i]=[];}
```

I don't know how it pars in terms of performance with the rest of the answers here, if you have a clue let me know in the comments.

If you don't know the length of the array beforehand pls have in mind that you can use either `push([])`, or `splice()` if you want to push/remove/replace a new element in place of an existing one.

Answer (score -2):

```
const grid = new Array(n).fill(new Array(n))
```

Comment: All the inner arrays will have the same reference. Changing one inner array will change all other inner arrays.
In most cases, This is not the desired behavior.