# How to shuffle characters in a vertical inverted pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, jagged-arrays

I have a string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" that I need to shuffle in a specific manner. To do that, I write the characters sequentially in columns bottom -> top and then left -> right (4 chars per column for example) until all characters are done. If the last column is not complete, then the empty spaces need to be on the bottom (this is very important). Like so:

> D H L N 
>   C G K M 
>   B F J 
>   A E I

The shuffle is accomplished by producing a new string reading the block of letters as we read text, in rows left -> right:

"DHLNCGKMBFJAEI"

The cases where the columns are not complete (word.size % column_height !=0) complicate things considerably.

I came up with a few solutions, but I'm not sure if there is a simpler (ie, shorter OR easier to read) and more elegant way of coding this problem. My solutions either have an ugly, separate block of code to handle the final incomplete column or seem way too complicated.

My question is, could it be done better?

If you don't want any spoilers and decide to try and figure it out for yourself, stop reading now. If you want to work from what I fiddled so far, then a working piece of code is

```js
var result = "";
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
var nr_rows = 4;
var current_row = 4;
var columns = Math.floor(str.length / nr_rows);
var modulus_table = str.length % nr_rows;
var modulus_position = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < nr_rows; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    result += str[current_row + j * nr_rows - 1];
  }
  if (modulus_table > 0) {
    result += str[str.length + modulus_position];
    modulus_table--;
    modulus_position--;
  }
  current_row--;
}
console.log(result);
```

Moving on to arrays, the next example would loop through each character, placing it correctly in a matrix-like array, but it doesn't work. The array needs to be created another way. For another example of this issue, see [How to create empty 2d array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512182/how-to-create-empty-2d-array-in-javascript). This would also need an ugly hack to fix the last characters on the last incomplete column aligning to the bottom instead of the top.

```js
var result = [[],[]];
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
var nr_rows = 4;
var row = nr_rows - 1;
var column = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  result[row][column] = str[i];
  row--;
  if (row < 0) {
    row = nr_rows;
    column++;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

This last method goes full matrix array, but it quickly becomes complicated, since it needs to loop through the array in 3 different directions. First, create a dummy array with the characters in the wrong place, but where the 'undefined' positions correspond to those that should be left empty. That is acomplished by populating the array 'rotated 90º' from the reading orientation.
Without this first step, the empty positions would be stacked at the bottom instead of the top.

A second pass is required to re-write the caracters in the correct places, skipping any holes in the matrix using the 'undefined' value. This check is made for every position and there is no separate block of code to handle an incomplete last line.

A third pass then reads every character in order to form the final shuffled string. All this seems way too complicated and confusing.

```js
// matrix populated top->bottom and left->right 
// with the characters in the wrong place 
// but the undefined postions in the correct place of the empty positions
var matrix = [];
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";
var rows = 4;
var columns = Math.ceil(str.length / rows);
var k = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  matrix[i] = [];
  for (var j = columns - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    matrix[i][j] = str[k];
    k++;
  }
}

// populate the matrix with the chars in the correct place and the 'undefined' positions left empty
var k = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
    if (matrix[i][j] != undefined) {
      matrix[i][j] = str[k];
      k++;
    }
  }
}

// read matrix in correct direction and send to string, skipping empty positions
var result = "";
for (var j = columns - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    if (matrix[i][j] != undefined) {
      result += matrix[i][j];
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: "*If the last row is not complete…*" should be "*If the last column…*".

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: Easier to read (you can use standard libraries and expressions): Split your operation into multiple standard matrix operations. 1. Reshape string into 4xn matrix, 2. Transpose matrix, 3. Horizontally mirror / flip matrix, 4. Shift last column, 5. Reshape matrix into 1x(mxn) string.

Comment: "If the last row is not complete…" should be "If the last column…" - fixed, thx

Comment: Not sure what's your exact requirement but if you want to put the characters from bottom to top, then shouldn't `M` and `N` be placed in last two rows rather than first two rows?

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `for` loop, `String.prototype.slice()` to to populate arrays with characters of string. Use `Array.prototype.pop()` within recursive function to get last element of array until each array `.length` is `0`.

To create array

```
  [
    ["D","H","L","N"],
    ["C","G","K","M"],
    ["B","F","J"],
    ["A","E","I"]
  ]
```

from vertically inverted string you can use `for` loop, `String.prototype.slice()` to set array of arrays containing elements having `.length` `4`, or `3` once `.length` of parent array is `2`, having been set with two arrays containing four elements

```js
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN";

function fnVerticalInvert(str, arr, res) {

  if (!arr && !res) {
    arr = []; res = "";
  }

  if (str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += 4) {
      arr.push([].slice.call(str.slice(i, i + 4)));
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length) {
      res += arr[i].pop()
    }
  }

  if (arr.some(function(curr) {return curr.length}))
    return fnVerticalInvert(null, arr, res);

  for (var i = 0, l = 4, j = 0, n = l - 1, k; i < l; i++, j += l) {
    if (i === l / 2) k = j;
    arr[i] = [].slice.call(res.slice(!k ? j : k, !k ? j + l : k + n));
    if (k) k += n;
  }

  return {str: res, arr:arr};

};

var res = fnVerticalInvert(str);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to return a string, I don't see why any intermediate result should use an array when it doesn't have to. The following could use one less array, but it's convenient to use *split* and an array to control the *while* loop rather than mutate the string.

The idea is to fill the strings from the bottom up until the column is full, then keep adding from the bottom of each column until it runs out of characters to assign. The row to start filling from is based on how many characters are left and how many rows there are.

Rather than building strings, it could build arrays but then generating a string requires multiple *joins*.

It can also produce results where there are insufficient slots for all the characters, so a result using 9 characters from 10 or more using a 3x3 "matrix" (see last example).

```js
function verticalShuffle(s, rows, cols) {
  var result = [''];
  s = s.split('');

  while (s.length && result[0].length < cols) {
    for (var i = (rows < s.length? rows : s.length) -1 ; i>=0; i--) {
      if (!result[i]) result[i] = '';
      result[i] += s.splice(0,1)[0] || '';
    }
  }
  return result.join('');
}

var s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMN';

console.log(verticalShuffle(s, 4, 4)); // DHLNCGKMBFJAEI
console.log(verticalShuffle(s, 6, 3)); // FLNEKMDJCIBHAG
// Only use 9 characters
console.log(verticalShuffle(s, 3, 3)); // CFIBEHADG
```

This uses plain ed3 functionality that will run in any browser. I don't see the point of restricting it to ECMAScript 2015 or later hosts.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just split/reverse the array into column groups, and convert to rows?

```
const result = str.match(/.{1,4}/g)    // split string into groups of 4
  .map(i => i.split('').reverse())     // reverse each group (bottom to top, and solves the last col issue)
  .reduce((res, col) => {              // reduce the groups into rows
    col.forEach((c, i) => res[i] += c) // concat each string char to the right row
    return res
  }, ['','','',''])                    // initialise empty strings per row
  .join('')                            // join the rows up
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/06L5nxj6/)