# Three Dimensional Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How Do we use Three Dimensional Array in Javascript?

Please show a basic example.

Comment: I believe you haven't tried or searched anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an empty multidimensional array in javascript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521796/is-it-possible-to-create-an-empty-multidimensional-array-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: yes i did but couldnt understand the concept that what is the use of this when we can do with normal array

Comment: Use of 3 dimensional is to store values like data of **3*3 rubic cube**

Answer (score 6):

> **Multi dimensional** array can be created like we create Single dimensional array in Javascript.

Creating Multi Dimensional array can be done by following:

```
var myArr = new Array();
myArr[0] = new Array();
myArr[0][0] = new Array()
myArr[0][0][0] = "test";
myArr[0][0][1] = "testnew";

alert(myArr[0][0][1]);
```

---

There is also another way to do it, to create 3 Dimensional array without assigning values:

```
var myArr = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
```