# push 3d array jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a function like below in jQuery

Ranges is declared for 3d array. This is getting inserted properly.
average is 2d array.

```
var ranges = [];
var averages = [];
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    alert([item.xAxisTime, item.upperBound, item.lowerBound]);
    ranges.push([item.xAxisTime, item.upperBound, item.lowerBound]);
    averages.push([item.xAxisTime, item.yAxisValue]);
});
```

i want to produce result like below

**2d array:**

```
averages = [
            [1246406400000, 21.5],
            [1246492800000, 22.1],
            [1246579200000, 23],
            [1246665600000, 23.8]];
```

**3d array**

```
ranges = [
            [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
            [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
            [1246579200000, 15.5, 29.6],
            [1246665600000, 16.7, 30.7]];
```

Comment: any console errors?, how do you know it doesn't push ?

Comment: Can you give an example array you want to process, what output your code is giving and the desired output for better understanding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Three Dimensional Array in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797786/three-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Example array to push into 3d array (ranges) is like below

'[22.5, 29.5, 19].
[21.5, 27.5, 15]'

Comment: This question is different from the existing one, where it was putting the value in desired index. But here i am pushing 3d value into an array.

Comment: There is no error message is popping, instead it does not append any proper values. when i try alerting the 3d array "ranges" it is coming empty

Comment: Please create a proper plnkr or code snippet for better understanding and to troubleshoot it quicker

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way, how i got my results.

```
var ranges = new Array();
var averages = new Array();
var arrAverage;
var arrRanges;
arrAverage = [item.xAxisTime, item.yAxisValue];
arrRanges = [item.xAxisTime, item.upperBound, item.lowerBound];
averages.push(arrAverage);
ranges.push(arrRanges);
```